# Eclipse shortcut to declare a variable name as method parameter

Tags: java, eclipse

Let's say we had a variable like this:

```
byte[] someByteArray;
```

And a method prototype like this:

```
public void someMethodRequiringString(String someByteArray);
```

And then we wanted to call our method on our byte array:

```
someMethodRequiringString(someByteArray);
```

Now we realize that our method requires a String instead. Let's also say we had already a conversion function in package **Util** called *convertFromByteArrayToString()*.
What's the best way to get from

```
someMethodRequiringString(someByteArray);
```

to

```
someMethodRequiringString(Util.convertFromByteArrayToString(someByteArray));
```

My way is to put the cursor in front of *someByteArray* and type in *Util.*, hit CTRL+Space and Eclipse suggests the method name of the conversion function. But, once I hit enter to choose this function, I will end up with something like this:

```
 someMethodRequiringString(Util.convertFromByteArrayToString(bytearray)someByteArray);
```

where **bytes** is the input parameter name declared in *Util.convertFromByteArrayToString(byte[] bytearray);*. I know this might be a beginner's question but what's the best practice here?

Comment: I don't understand how prefixing my attribute will bring me from *someMethodRequiringString(someByteArray);* to *someMethodRequiringString(Util.convertFromByteArrayToString(someByteArray));* in one step. Please mind that I asked for a shortcut.

Comment: @Aubin That won't help in this case. Also, it's a pretty outdated practice these days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to have code completion overwrite the existing code (instead of inserting it before the existing text) as described here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse/article.html#tips_completion

Alternatively you may also consider deleting the already written method argument `someByteArray` hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> 3 times (if your cursor is in front of it) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd> 3 times (if your cursor is directly after the argument). Then you add your Utils method via code completion as you do now and then you have the byte array argument be re-added by code completion (as Eclipse will suggest your variable as best choice, even without any character written yet).

The second alternative may sound complicated at first, but should make you type this much more quick if used often.

Comment: Very good recommendations and exactly what I needed. Thank you.